# My mathematical expression converter doesn't print correctly

Tags: c++, parsing

So, I am writing a program which takes the input (a mathematical expression) and converts it into postfix notation and then print it out to the user. When I perform this program on simple mathematical expressions (i.e. `5 + 1 - 3 * 2`) it works great. The problem is when I include parentheses. It prints all of the mathematical operators on the last line instead of their proper place. I need the mathematical operators to be in their proper spot. (i. e. `5 1 + 3 - 2 *`). Any suggestions?

The real output of this statement `5 - ( 2 * 3 ) + 5` is `5 2 3 5 * - +` I need it to look like `5 2 3 * - 5 +`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int priority(string item) //prioritizing the operators
{
  if(item == "(" || item == ")")
  {
    return 0;
  }
  else if(item == "+" || item == "-")
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else if(item == "/" || item == "*")
  {
    return 2;
  }
}
void welcome()
{
 cout << "blah blah!" << endl;
 }
int main()
{   

welcome(); // welcome text

stack <string> myStack; 
char line[256]; 
cin.getline( line, 256); 
string exp = line;
string item;
string output = ""; 

istringstream iss(exp);

iss >> item;

while(iss)
{
    if(item != "+" && item != "-" && item != "/" && item != "*" && item != "(" && item != ")") //If the char is a number
    {
        cout << item << endl;
    }
    else if(myStack.size() == 0) // If the stack is empty
    {
        myStack.push(item);
    }
    else if( item == "+" || item == "-" || item == "/" || item == "*") //If the char is an operator
    {
        if(priority(myStack.top()) < priority(item)) // the item on the stack is greater priority than the array item
        {
            myStack.push(item);
        }
        else
        {
            while(myStack.size() > 0 && priority(myStack.top()) >= priority(item)) //while the stack contains something, and the item on 
            {           
                string dpu = myStack.top();
                myStack.pop();
                output = output + dpu + " "; 
            }
            myStack.push(item);
        }
    }
    else if(item == "(") // left peren
    {
        myStack.push(item);
    }
    else if(item == ")") // right peren
    {
        while(myStack.top() != "(")
        {
            string dpu = myStack.top();  
            myStack.pop();
            output = output + dpu + " "; 
        }
        myStack.pop();
    }
    iss>> item; 
}
while (myStack.size() > 0 )
{
    string dpu = myStack.top(); 
    output = output + dpu + " ";
    myStack.pop();
}
cout<< output << endl;
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging? Step through the program line by line and check whether the variables contain the values you expect. At some point they will not contain the correct values or print the correct string. There is the bug.

Comment: The first `if` in `main` prevents any numbers from **ever** being added to your stack.  You should probably write this algorithm in pseudocode first and only convert to C++ when you fully understand the pseudocode.

Comment: replace `cout << item << endl;` by `output += item + " ";` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

well... in your code the numbers are always printed before anything else:

```
if (item != "+" && item != "-" && item != "/" && item != "*" && item != "(" && item != ")") //If the char is a number
{
    cout << item << endl;
}
```

I'm not familiar with the notation you are requesting, but a stack doesn't seem to me the right datastructure for this task... using a tree seems better to me, since you are parsing

Comment: A stack is reasonable and typical for generating postfix notation.  The rest of your answer seems valid, though.